# How do I get a pointer to a struct, given as a value in a function?

Tags: function, pointers, compare, structure

I want to delete an element of a linked list, and for that i have to compare the elements with the one given in the header, but the value is a structure and I cant compare 2 structures. So I guess I need to get a pointer to that structure and compare those two. How is that done? Thats kinda the function:

```
void delete_element(NodList* head, Structure value){
NodList* moving;
while (moving->next != NULL && moving->val != value){
left_behind = moving;
moving = moving->next;
}
```

//in the rest i delete if its matching and move the pointers

Comment: I didn't check the rest of your code for correctness, but if the goal is to remove an element from the list given a reference element ('value' in your code), you'll need to decide what it means for two elements to be equal. For what you posted, it looks like you'd need to implement one or more overloaded operators for the `Structure` type in an appropriate way (where what's appropriate depends on the `Structure` type).

Comment: I'll add that even if you were to convert the body of your function to perform a pointer comparison, it will never evaluate to equal because the 'value' argument is a new, temporary object that only exists for that particular invocation of the function. There are other scenarios where pointer comparison could work though.